# Многотабличный запрос в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.

есть таблица с именами. **names**

```
id | name
 1 | alex
 2 | kate
 3 | jack
```

есть другая таблица **connect**

```
id_a | id_b
   1 | 2
   2 | 3
   3 | 1
```

Вопрос: какой запрос написать чтобы вытащить следующее:

```
alex|kate
kate|jack
jack|alex
```

результат такой же как и в таблице **connect** только вместо **id** их значение

Спасибо за ваше внимание.

Comment: к таблице `connect` два раза джойните таблицу `names` (с разными алиасами) по соответствующим полям и получаете нужный результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это, у меня работало на 100%.

```
SELECT
      (SELECT n.name FROM names n WHERE n.id = c.id_a) AS 'col1',
      (SELECT n.name FROM names n WHERE n.id = c.id_b) AS 'col2'
FROM connect c
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  a.name AS id_a,
  b.name AS id_b
FROM
  connect AS c
LEFT JOIN
  names AS a
ON
  c.id_a = a.id
LEFT JOIN
  name AS b
On
  c.id_b = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   ns.name 
   ,ns2.name
from 
   names ns
   ,connect c
left join names as ns2 
     on (c.id_b= ns2.id)
where c.id_a= ns.id
```